# prove $|v\rangle = |a\rangle + ( \frac{T|v\rangle}{T|u\rangle})|u\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, mathematical-physics

I have a linear map $T:\mathbb R^n  \rightarrow \mathbb R$. and this map is not a constant map that get all vectors into $0$ vector.
if I have a vector  $|u\rangle \in R^n$  and  $|u\rangle \notin \operatorname{Ker}(T)$, how to prove that for any vector $|v\rangle$ in $\mathbb R^n$ there is a vector $|a\rangle$ in $\operatorname{Ker}(T)$ such that:

$|v\rangle = |a\rangle + ( \frac{T|v\rangle}{T|u\rangle})|u\rangle$

and what does this mean?

note: $\frac{T|v\rangle}{T|u\rangle}$ means vector $T|v\rangle$ is divided by $T|u\rangle$ and this is could happen when one vector is a coefficient of the another vector.

Comment: Use \rangle to produce $\rangle$.

Comment: @Amir The expressions $(T |v\rangle/T|u\rangle)$ and $(T |v\rangle\div T|u\rangle)$ are not standard notation, nor is it clear from the context what this could mean. If you want an answer to your question, you will have to either tell us what this notation means or give us more context

Comment: @Amir What does it mean for one vector to be "a coefficient of" another vector? For example, if $|u\rangle = (1,2,3)$ and $|v\rangle = (3,2,1)$, then what is $\frac {|u\rangle}{|v\rangle}$? What about if $|v\rangle = (1,0,0)$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann the result of dividing two vectors that are coefficients of each other is a scalar. for instance $T|v\rangle = (1, 2, 3)$ and $T|u\rangle = (2, 4, 6) = 2 T|v\rangle $ and then $\frac{T|v\rangle}{T|u\rangle} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Amir Now I understand. I have never seen the phrase that "one vector is a coefficient of the other" because the term "coefficient" always refers to a scalar. The relationship you're referring to is typically expressed as "one vector is a **multiple of** the other". Even within that context, I have never seen one vector divided by the other, so thank you for explaining.

Comment: @AmirBonari Also, I just noticed that $T$ is a function to $\Bbb R$, so it makes perfect sense to divide $T |u \rangle$ by $T |v \rangle$ because we are dividing scalars. Sorry for not noticing sooner.

Comment: @AmirBonari When you say "what does this mean", is that a part of the original question, or are you asking what the question means?

Comment: @BenGrossmann you're welcome.

I mean, that formula doesn't make sense for me and I can't understand where does it come from.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If we work backwards from the expression given, we see that for such a vector $|a \rangle$ to exist, it would have to be true that
$$
|a \rangle = |v \rangle - \frac{T|v\rangle}{T|u\rangle} |u \rangle.
$$
Show that this vector $|a\rangle$ will always be an element of $\ker T$. That is, show that $T|a\rangle = 0$.

Comment: oh! that's a good hint. thank you.
But I changed this method a little and I wrote this. Do you think this way makes sense and right?

$T|v\rangle = T|v\rangle \rightarrow T|v\rangle =  \frac{T|v\rangle}{T|u\rangle}T|u\rangle \rightarrow T|v\rangle = 0 + ( \frac{T|v\rangle}{T|u\rangle})T|u\rangle \rightarrow T|v\rangle = T|a\rangle + ( \frac{T|v\rangle}{T|u\rangle})T|u\rangle \rightarrow  |a\rangle \in ker(T) \rightarrow |v\rangle = |a\rangle + ( \frac{T|v\rangle}{T|u\rangle})|u\rangle$

Comment: Your steps don't make sense to me. In particular, I don't understand the step $T|v\rangle = T|a\rangle + ( \frac{T|v\rangle}{T|u\rangle})T|u\rangle \rightarrow  |a\rangle \in ker(T)$

Comment: I mean, since $T|a\rangle = 0$ so $|a\rangle  \in \operatorname{Ker}(T) $

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that the issue was going from $T |v \rangle = T |a \rangle + \frac{T|v \rangle}{T|u\rangle}T|u\rangle$ to $|v\rangle = |a\rangle + \frac{T|v \rangle}{T|u \rangle}|u\rangle$.

Comment: It's clear becuase: $T|v\rangle - T|a\rangle - \frac{T|v\rangle}{T|u\rangle} T|u\rangle = 0$ and because $T$ is linear so $T|v - a - \frac{T|v\rangle}{T|u\rangle} u\rangle = 0$ 

and again because T is not a constant $0$ map so for this equation to be true we must have:

$|v\rangle - |a\rangle -\frac{T|v\rangle}{T|u\rangle} -  |u\rangle = 0$ so $|v\rangle = |a\rangle +\frac{T|v\rangle}{T|u\rangle} +  |u\rangle $


But I agree, I explained it first a little bad!

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $T|x \rangle = 0$ implies that $|x \rangle = 0$, but this is not the case. We can only say that $T|x\rangle = 0$ implies that $|x \rangle \in \ker(T)$.